# Overriding << operator for templated struct

Tags: c++

`numcpp.h` file

```
    #include "iostream"        

    namespace numcpp{

    template<typename T>
    struct Vector
    {
        std::vector<T> v;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Matrix
    {
        std::vector<T> m;

        //template<typename T>
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const mf& mat);
    };

    typedef Vector<float> vf;
    typedef Matrix<vf> mf;
    }
```

I am trying to overload << operator for cout to be able to print `mf`. First I tried making the overloading function a friend that directly takes `mf` as argument. I did this because if I took `Matrix` as argument, I would need to deal with template and I don't know how to do that.

`numcpp.cpp` file

```
#include "numcpp.h"

namespace numcpp{

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const mf& mat) 
{
    //overloaded out here
    return out;
}
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "iostream"
#include "numcpp.h"

int main()
{
    numcpp::mf inputs;
    // inputs is filled with random numbers here
    std::cout << inputs;
}
```

But this gives an error `identified mf is undefined` in .h file in line `friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const mf& mat);`

So I ditched this approach and tried removing the friend function declaration from `Matrix` without changing the .cpp file. But now I get a different error saying `no operator << matches these operands`.
I think this is because the overload is done in `numcpp` namespace so it is not visible from `main` which is outside the namesapce.

Comment: Your numcpp.cpp doesn't include iostream or numcpp.h, and your numcpp.h doesn't include vector. (Or it does, in which case you should [edit] your question to include a [mcve].)

Comment: @Sneftel It does, I just edited it in. I was just trying to keep the question short.

Comment: Is the lack of name on the namespace in `numcpp.cpp` a typo? You can replace `mf` with `Matrix` in your friend declaration. Using it without template parameter within the definition always refers to the current instatiation. You can however not put the definition of a template in a `.cpp` file (you can, but then you need to explicitly instatiate that template for every type that should be usable with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you normally want is to define a template in your header file. The definition needs to be available at the call-site to allow the compiler to make an instatiation of the template.

If possible, the easiest way is to put the definition in the class definition.

```
template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;

    // using Matrix here is allowed and refers to the current instatiation, equivalent to writing Matrix<T>
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Matrix& mat) {
        ...
        return out;
    }
};
```

Comment: @I just noticed it works even if inline is removed. Is there is reason to make it inline here?

Comment: No. `inline` will allow multiple definitions to exist, so it's usefull if you want to put a definition of a function in a header file and include it in multiple places, but when the definition is inside the class it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your *numcpp.h* to

```cpp
namespace numcpp{

template<typename T>
struct Vector
{
    std::vector<T> v;
};

typedef Vector<float> vf;

template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;

    //template<typename T>
    inline friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Matrix<vf>& mat);
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const  Matrix<vf>& mat)
{
    //overloaded out here
    return out;
}


typedef Matrix<vf> mf;
}
```

You are getting this error because mf was not declared when you trying to use it.

Also, you can add the body of the function directly in the definition to get rid of the inline.

Answer (score 0):

The typedefs are not available inside the definition of your class `Matrix`. You can either declare the typedef before the class definition (@Alloces' answer) of just template the overloaded operator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace numcpp {

template<typename T>
struct Vector
{
    std::vector<T> v;
};

template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;

    template<typename K> // template parameter must not be named T
    inline friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Matrix<K>& mat);
};

template<typename K>
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const  Matrix<K>& mat)
{
    return out << "Just a test";
}

typedef Vector<float> vf;
typedef Matrix<vf> mf;
}

int main() {
    numcpp::mf inputs;
    std::cout << inputs << "\n";  // Just a test
}
```